# ASP.NET MVC application querying Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-active-directory

I have a scenario where I want to search Active Directory (AD) for users.
Basically I want to query the AD based on a substring

Example - Query string Jimmy should return all the users whose name start with Jimmy.

```
        string userName = "Jimmy"
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("alias");

        searcher.SizeLimit = 5;
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname=" + userName + "*))";

        SearchResultCollection searchResults = searcher.FindAll();
```

This snippet does not yield any results at all from the web application. However this snippet works from on a console application..
I have not added any references in the web.config file at the moment.

Am I missing out some configuration for the communication between ASP.NET MVC application and Active Directory to happen ?

Comment: Sounds like a configuration discrepancy if it works from your console application but not the web application.

Comment: Thanks for your update @Coulton. I changed the IIS authentication settings for the site from Anonymous to windows and this snippet works now.

Comment: Great to hear.  I have added it as an answer in case anyone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a configuration discrepancy if it works from your console application but not the web application